# Unable to test HTTP PUT-based file upload via Squid Proxy

Tags: http, upload, proxy, squid, put

I can upload a file to my Apache web server using Curl just fine:

```
echo "[$(date)] file contents." | curl -T - http://WEB-SERVER/upload/sample.put
```

However, if I put a Squid proxy server in between, then I am not able to:

```
echo "[$(date)] file contents." | curl -x http://SQUID-PROXY:3128 -T - http://WEB-SERVER/upload/sample.put
```

Curl reports the following error:

*Note: This error response was in HTML format, but I've removed the tags for ease of reading.*

```
ERROR: The requested URL could not be retrieved

ERROR
The requested URL could not be retrieved

While trying to retrieve the URL:
http://WEB-SERVER/upload/sample.put

The following error was encountered:
Unsupported Request Method and Protocol

Squid does not support all request methods for all access protocols.
For example, you can not POST a Gopher request.
Your cache administrator is root.
```

My `squid.conf` doesn't seem to be having any ACL/rule that should disallow based on the `src` or `dst` IP addresses, or the `protocol`, or the HTTP `method`... **as I can do an `HTTP POST` just fine between the same client and the web server, with the same proxy sitting in between.**

In case of the failing `HTTP PUT` case, to see the request and response traffic that was actually occurring, I placed a `netcat` process in between Curl and Squid, and this is what I saw:

**Request:**

```
PUT http://WEB-SERVER/upload/sample.put HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.15.5 (i686-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.15.5 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5
Host: WEB-SERVER
Pragma: no-cache
Accept: */*
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Expect: 100-continue
```

**Response:**

```
HTTP/1.0 501 Not Implemented
Server: squid/2.6.STABLE21
Date: Sun, 13 May 2012 02:11:39 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 1078
Expires: Sun, 13 May 2012 02:11:39 GMT
X-Squid-Error: ERR_UNSUP_REQ 0
X-Cache: MISS from SQUID-PROXY-FQDN
X-Cache-Lookup: NONE from SQUID-PROXY-FQDN:3128
Via: 1.0 SQUID-PROXY-FQDN:3128 (squid/2.6.STABLE21)
Proxy-Connection: close

<SNIPPED the HTML error response already shown earlier above>
```

*Note: I have anonymized the IP addresses and server names throughout for readability reasons.*

Comment: I think the problem is the Expect header. Can you remove it? Because the PUT method is supported by Squid.

Comment: I tried (with the `-H "Expect:"` option) but still the same response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Amos Jeffries for answering this on [squid-users forum](http://squid-web-proxy-cache.1019090.n4.nabble.com/Unable-to-test-HTTP-PUT-based-file-upload-via-Squid-Proxy-td4634404.html). The issue is basically that Squid before version 3.1 does not implement HTTP 1.1 and thus rejects the chunked transfer encoding.