# Squid proxy gives 501 on GET request made by python but not curl

Tags: python, sockets, http, curl, squid

So I have a program to download webpages using bare sockets. I have to use bare sockets and can't use anything like requests or urllib etc. I'm on a network behind a Squid proxy, so my python program simply `connect`'s to the proxy server and makes GET requests for the objects which I fetch from a HAR file. I tested the request using curl like

```
curl https://apis.google.com/_/scs/abc-static/_/js/k=gapi.gapi.en.wgbKiK972Ko.O/m=gapi_iframes,googleapis_client,plusone/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/rs=AItRSTOlX0YCaQmKijyj5lpKQ5AVm7UE6A/cb=gapi.loaded_0 -o out_file
```

and I get the output as the proper entire file. I inspected the header for the response and they are

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8
Last-Modified: Thu, 11 Dec 2014 20:44:59 GMT
Date: Fri, 12 Dec 2014 03:38:46 GMT
Expires: Sat, 12 Dec 2015 03:38:46 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Server: sffe
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000
Age: 1065247
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic,p=0.02
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Now I tried to do the same thing using socket programming in python:

```
    HOST = 'proxy.address.of.squid.proxy'
    PORT = 3128
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    url = 'https://apis.google.com/_/scs/abc-static/_/js/k=gapi.gapi.en.wgbKiK972Ko.O/m=gapi_iframes,googleapis_client,plusone/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/rs=AItRSTOlX0YCaQmKijyj5lpKQ5AVm7UE6A/cb=gapi.loaded_0'
    httpVrsn = 'HTTP/1.1'
    domain = 'apis.google.com'
    objReq = 'GET '+url+' '+httpVrsn+'\r\nHost: '+domain+'\r\n\r\n';
    s.send(objReq);
    data = '';
    try:
        data = s.recv(1024);
        print data
    # other non-relevant stuff
```

the output I get is

> ```
> HTTP/1.0 501 Not Implemented
> Server: squid/3.1.19
> Mime-Version: 1.0
> Date: Wed, 24 Dec 2014 10:25:42 GMT
> Content-Type: text/html
> Content-Length: 3576
> X-Squid-Error: ERR_UNSUP_REQ 0
> Vary: Accept-Language
> Content-Language: en
> X-Cache: MISS from localhost
> X-Cache-Lookup: NONE from localhost:3128
> Via: 1.0 localhost (squid/3.1.19)
> Connection: close
>
> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
> <html><head>
> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
> <title>ERROR: The requested URL could not be retrieved</title>
> <style type="text/css"><!-- 
>  /*
>  Stylesheet for Squid Error pages
>  Adapted from design by Free CSS Templates
>  http://www.freecsstemplates.org
>  Released for free under a Creative Commons Attribution 2.5 License
> */
>
> /* Page basics */
> * {
>   font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
> }
>
> html body {
>   margin: 0;
>   padding: 0;
>   background: #efefef;
>   font-size: 12px;
>   color: #1e1e1e;
> }
> ```

so I checked out [this](https://alpacapowered.wordpress.com/2014/05/08/squid-and-chunked-transfer-encoding-shenanigans/) which explained that my Squid proxy 3.1 doesn't support **Transfer-Encoding: chunked** but it says that's the case for POST requests, I'm not sure if it holds for GET requests as well. I also checked out [Unable to test HTTP PUT-based file upload via Squid Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568655/unable-to-test-http-put-based-file-upload-via-squid-proxy). I'm not able to understand how is curl or even my browser able to fetch the content when requested on the same network behind the same proxy but through python I'm not able to fetch the response successfully?

So is there any way to get my python program to work without tweaking with the Squid Proxy, since I don't have control over the proxy.

Comment: Maybe site on the other end or squid does not like your user agent. Try using mechanize.Browser and set user agent that says your python program is e.g. Firefox.

Comment: If that's the case, I'm just curious what User-Agent does curl use? As far as I checked, by default curl doesn't have any User-Agent and it still works so probably that's not the reason, but I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

Curl uses the CONNECT method, which is a tunneling method. The proxy simply connects on the TCP level to the remote side and curl does all the communication including TLS handshake. All TCP/IP packets are just 'shoveled' back and forth by the proxy. But beware, silent intercepting (MITM) by the proxy is possible under certain coditions (e.g. when the admin/company puts his own CA cert into your cert pool).

What your python script does is asking the proxy to communicate with the remote side. Somehow your proxy isn't able to do the TLS connection (not configured or disabled during build, or simply not capable otherwise).

To configure Squid see http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/HTTPS